# Subjunctive questions

Tags: subjunctive-mood, that, irrealis-were

Do I need to add ‘that’? Is it neccesary?

She demands that he go to the mall.

She demands he go to the mall.

Which one is proper?

I thought that he was tired.

I thought he were tired.

There are some instances where subjunctive ‘that’ is used - possible. Is ‘were’ preferred or ‘that’?  Please advise.

Comment: No, "that" is optional in your first example.  But your third example is not a subjunctive, though "that" is optional. Your fourth example is ungrammatical -- "was" is required here.

Comment: Based on what I’ve studied from multiple sources, *thought* is a non-factual. The "past subjunctive" (irrealis) form *were* is also used by some as an alternative to the backshifted indicative *was* following if or whether in indirect speech or thought. Example: He sometimes wondered whether he *were* being affected by the diet . . . (Iris Murdoch: The Good Apprentice, 1985). What I’m not sure about is its use in modern English. Do you know?

Comment: "Thought" may be non-factual, but that doesn't mean that "I thought he were tired" is subjunctive -- it's not, and in any case it's ungrammatical". The ill-named past subjunctive "were" that you allude to typically occurs in conditional constructions like "If I were a rich man ...".

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you use the subjunctive in English depends on more than whether something is "non-factual". Certain verbs can take the subjunctive and others can't, even though their meanings may seem similar.

The use of the subjunctive after verbs like *wonder* is slowly fading from the English language. However, the subjunctive has never been used after the verb *thought*. See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+wondered+if+he+was%2C+I+wondered+if+he+were%2CI+thought+that+he+were%2C+I+thought+that+he+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20wondered%20if%20he%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20wondered%20if%20he%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20that%20he%20was%3B%2Cc0) for confirmation.

For another illustration of this, Shakespeare wrote:

> I wonder if the lion be to speak.

and

> 'Tis thought that Richmond is their admiral;

with the subjunctive after *wonder* and the indicative after *thought*.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, with perfect grammatical correctness, "She demands he go to the mall."

If you did so, in the UK at any rate, you would be faced with a mixture of incomprehension, ridicule, and a bit of admiration. That use of the subjunctive is now antique. Personally I quite like it, hence the admiration, but most modern users of the language would regard it as odd.

Comment: Let me know when grammaticality catches up with idiomaticity. I'll keep using 'She insists that he goes to the mall' when previous context forces the 'demand' sense (_or_ the won't-be-gainsaid sense).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Is it not that when one uses non-factual (subjunctive) word one must remove the ‘s’? Third person word should not be used in such context. Is it not to be written like ‘She insists that he *go* to the mall’?

Comment: To my ear, omitting the 'that' sounds British or rather elite for an American (lol funny that a shortcut would feel more elite) .. but this answer makes it seem elite on the old side of the pond too.  I also love the subjunctive tense and think our throwing it aside says a lot about how our culture is less contemplative and analytical by nature - "what's the takeaway" .. not "let's examine the hypothetical outcomes here"

Comment: It's not at all antique in the U.S.

Comment: @PeterShor Very interesting. I did say 'in the UK...'